# Unity. Проблема с созданием апк файла

Tags: android, unity3d, unity3d-android, build-error

Столкнулся с вот такой проблемой в Unity. Никак не могу компилировать апк файл, до добавление рекламы от самого юнити все работало норм, теперь же вылазит это, хотя при проверке в самом юнити рекламу выводит и игра работает как надо. Версия юнити - Unity 2022.3.1f1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код самих ошибок. Первая ошибка:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\38095\UnityProject\Casual Game(2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\38095\UnityProject\Casual Game(2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file 'C:\Users\38095\UnityProject\Casual Game(2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\build.gradle': 1: Unexpected input: '{' @ line 1, column 13.
     allprojects {
                 ^
  
  1 error


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1s

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Вторая ошибка:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-7.2.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

Environment Variables:
USERDOMAIN = DESKTOP-OELU6RD
ProgramFiles = C:\Program Files
EFC_13780 = 1
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = AMD64
PROCESSOR_REVISION = 8e0c
OneDriveConsumer = C:\Users\38095\OneDrive
OS = Windows_NT
CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME = \\.\pipe\crashpad_18748_YVVKAKJPOXPIMOLE
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 12, GenuineIntel
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY = 28f3cae0b33b8b3702120c9ed1a935aa
USERPROFILE = C:\Users\38095
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK
CommonProgramFiles = C:\Program Files\Common Files
DriverData = C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
ComSpec = C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
LAUNCH_DARKLY_CLIENT_TOKEN = 60a7e30fafc7e60e33446283
PSModulePath = C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
PUBLIC = C:\Users\Public
SystemRoot = C:\WINDOWS
HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN = 1717415662
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = 8
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_STAGING = 83ee04fccc67e4fcc7dd527c4c6f1e21
WOOTRIC_CLIENT_TOKEN = NPS-aa8be4c3
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
DEBUG_ENV_VAR = UnityHub
ProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files
FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING = Internet Explorer
HOMEDRIVE = C:
TEMP = C:\Users\38095\AppData\Local\Temp
Path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\Bpl;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin64;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\Bpl\Win64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Bpl;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\bin64;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Bpl\Win64;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\38095\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\38095\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\38095\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\38095\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
USERNAME = 38095
COMPUTERNAME = DESKTOP-OELU6RD
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE = DESKTOP-OELU6RD
PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
SystemDrive = C:
ALLUSERSPROFILE = C:\ProgramData
SENTRY_ACCESS_TOKEN = 3df78d9e53f8456aa90fbae044ce1a6261421ab1d0014674bc2e933477289017
HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN_STAGING = 3786794399
TMP = C:\Users\38095\AppData\Local\Temp
FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING = Default
windir = C:\WINDOWS
ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN = 1
CommonProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
APPDATA = C:\Users\38095\AppData\Roaming
PROCESSOR_LEVEL = 6
CommonProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files\Common Files
ProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)
NVIDIAWHITELISTED = 0x01
SESSIONNAME = Console
LOGONSERVER = \\DESKTOP-OELU6RD
LOCALAPPDATA = C:\Users\38095\AppData\Local
HOMEPATH = \Users\38095
LAUNCH_DARKLY_CLIENT_TOKEN_STAGING = 60a7e30fafc7e60e33446282
SHIM_MCCOMPAT = 0x810000001
OneDrive = C:\Users\38095\OneDrive
ProgramData = C:\ProgramData
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = undefined


stderr[
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\38095\UnityProject\Casual Game(2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\38095\UnityProject\Casual Game(2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file 'C:\Users\38095\UnityProject\Casual Game(2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\build.gradle': 1: Unexpected input: '{' @ line 1, column 13.
     allprojects {
                 ^
  
  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <9b16f93a6ed84389a6076e762cd925b0>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <9b16f93a6ed84389a6076e762cd925b0>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <9b16f93a6ed84389a6076e762cd925b0>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <9b16f93a6ed84389a6076e762cd925b0>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <9b16f93a6ed84389a6076e762cd925b0>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <9b16f93a6ed84389a6076e762cd925b0>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <9b16f93a6ed84389a6076e762cd925b0>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <9b16f93a6ed84389a6076e762cd925b0>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смог решить эту проблему. Оставлю это здесь на случай если у кого-то будут такие же проблемы. По крайней мере в моем случае это сработало.

Я просто зашел в папку Assets->Plugins->Android и удалил все файли с этой папки, после этого у меня все скомпилировалось без единой ошибки и на телефоне проект работал без проблем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]